# use geocomplete to do a nearby search

Tags: jquery, geocoding, geocomplete

I'm using geocomplete (a jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete Plugin).

What's the best way to do a nearby search? (e.g. search for addresses in a city)

I know this can be done by specifying the 'location' or the 'bounds' for a map, e.g.

```
 $(function(){    
    $("#geocomplete_user").geocomplete({
        map: ".map_canvas",
        details: ".details",
        detailsAttribute: "geo",
        types: ["geocode"],
        location: [-37.817792, 144.96722899999997]
    });
})
```

...but I don't want to use a map. I just want to have a drop-down menu.

Comment: Maybe something like this: [http://tompi.github.io/jeoquery/ui.html](http://tompi.github.io/jeoquery/ui.html)

Comment: something like this?
http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/simple.html